# JavaFx: when Jdialog dispose close main window

Tags: java, swing, javafx, jdialog

I recently started a JavaFX project, and I've a problem with a `JDialog` Swing modal dialog in my application. I've a `JDesktopPane` in which I've drawed a graph using a Javafx `JFXPanel`. The `JDesktopPane` also have a popmenu, using the popumenu I've launch a modal Jdialog. The `Jdialog` have a `setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);`

The problem is when I close Jdialog window via x in the upper right corner o via `this.dispose()`, whole program terminates as if I was closing the main window.

The problem arise under Linux, but under Windows it's work correctly.

Someone can help me ?

Comment: This sounds like a bug. What version of Java and JavaFX are you using? Did you try different versions?